# Flex doesn't export resources to release build

Tags: flexbuilder, release-builds

I'm trying to set image source conditionaly using the following line:

```
source="{data.muted ? '/assets/audioMuted.gif' : '/assets/audio.gif'}"
```

Apps run fine when run from Flex builder, but when I try to export release build from Flex builder, those gif files are not exported.

Does anybody have an idea what to do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the assets. Flexbuilder will never add an image to your swf unless you Embed it.
If you looked at a tool such as [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what called your app is making you'd see one of those images being called and you can't have placed them into an appropriate folder.

```
[Embed("/assets/picture.gif")]
private const IMAGE1:Class;
[Embed("/assets/picture2.gif")]
private const IMAGE2:Class;
```

then you would do

```
source="{data.muted ? IMAGE1: IMAGE2 }"
```

that should do as long as the embed path is correct (flexbuilder will tell you if it isn't).